# Is the following equivalent to $f$ is discontinuous at $x_0$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If a function $f$ is defined in a neighborhood of $a \in \mathbb{R}^p$, we say $f$ is continuous if for any neighborhood $B(f(a), \epsilon)$ of $f(a)$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ there exists a neighborhood $B(a, \delta)$ of $\mathbb{R}^p$ such that $f(B(a, \delta)) \subset B(f(a), \epsilon)$.

Is the following equivalent to saying $f$ is discontinous at $x_0$?

There exists no $\epsilon >0$ and no $\delta >0$ such that $f(B(x_0, \delta)) \subset B(f(x_0), \epsilon)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ is continuous when $$\forall \varepsilon>0\quad\exists\delta>0  \quad f(B(a,\delta))\subset B(f(a),\epsilon).$$

The negation of this statement would be (quantors are replaced by their counterparts and logic expressions are negated):

$$\exists \varepsilon>0\quad\forall  \delta>0\quad  f(B(a,\delta))\not\subset B(f(a),\epsilon).$$

Your version writes $$\forall \varepsilon>0\quad \forall \delta>0 \quad f(B(a,\delta))\not\subset B(f(a),\epsilon).$$